# Недействительный сертификат SSL Nginx

Tags: nginx, golang, debian, ssl, tls

Настраиваю свой сервер на Debian 11. Ставлю Nginx, сайт на Golang, настраиваю всё это для нормальной работы. По итогу сам сайт работает корректно, но SSL сертификат помечается как недействительный. Использовал по началу сертификат от OpenSSL, затем от Let's Encrypt, оба помечаются как недействительные. Ниже привожу команды, которые использую для настройки сервера. При заходе на сайт выдает ошибку NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

```
### Установка проекта
mkdir /var/servers
cd /var/servers
git clone https://github.com/evgen1ck/test-server.git
cd test-server
go mod init main.go
go mod tidy
go mod download
go build main.go

### Настройка nginx
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 5479 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/test-domain-com -subj '/C=/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=' -out /etc/ssl/certs/test-domain-com.pem

rm -r /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
rm -r /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# Создаем файл test.service
echo '[Unit]
Description=test
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/var/servers/test-server/main
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target' >> /lib/systemd/system/test.service

# Создаем файл test.domain.com
echo 'server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/test-domain-com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/test-domain-com.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m;
    ssl_session_timeout 60m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:9990;
        proxy_cookie_domain localhost test.domain.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}' >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.domain.com

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.domain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.domain.com
sudo nginx -s reload
sudo service test start

# Далее заменял существующий сертификат на от CertBot
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx -y
sudo certbot --nginx -d test.domain.com
```

Comment: Вы создали самоподписанный сертификат. Разумеется ему никто не доверяет. Покажите команду, как вы получали сертификат от let's encrypt

Comment: @PakUula решил заново поработать с certbot. SSL сертификат был от lets encrypt, но отображался как недействительный в гугл хроме, хоть и чистил кэш через ctrl + shift + del. Попробовал зайди с другого браузера или телефона, отображается как доверенный.

Comment: Ну раз с других браузеров показывается как доверенный, значит доверенный. Мало ли как заглючил ваш тестовый браузер.